# AWS EC2 RHEL 7 auditd service running but can not connect to remote server

Tags: amazon-ec2, rhel7

I have 3 RHEL-7 EC2 instances. All can connect among themselves using private IP. One client and server are on same subnet and the other client is from different VPC but can connect with other two instances over VPC Peering. rsyslog is running on the server and clients are sending logs (/var/log/messages and /var/log/secure) to the server instance over port 514. for the sake of simplicity firewalld/iptables are stopped and selinux is permissive/disabled.

I have configured auditd on the clients, the service is active(running) but audit logs are not being transferred to the server. Below is the details of "systemctl status auditd" of client:

[root@ip-10-0-3-159 ~]# systemctl status auditd
● auditd.service - Security Auditing Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-07-11 19:42:48 UTC; 38s ago
     Docs: man:auditd(8)
           https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-documentation
  Process: 386 ExecStartPost=/sbin/augenrules --load (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 375 ExecStart=/sbin/auditd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 376 (auditd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/auditd.service
           ├─376 /sbin/auditd
           └─378 /sbin/audispd

Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audisp-remote[436]: Error connecting to 10.0.1.238: Network is unreachable
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote terminated unexpectedly
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audisp-remote[451]: Error connecting to 10.0.1.238: Network is unreachable
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote terminated unexpectedly
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote terminated unexpectedly
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote has exceeded max_restarts
Jul 11 19:42:48 ip-10-0-3-159.ec2.internal audispd[378]: plugin /sbin/audisp-remote was restarted

I have tried both public ip and private ip (as remote_server) in /etc/audisp/audisp-remote.conf, I can telnet to port 60 of the remote server from the clients, there is no issue with security group and most importantly the same configuration worked successfully on VM environment.

Below is "netstat -tulpen" of server:
[root@ip-10-0-1-238 ~]# netstat -tulpen
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:514             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18570      1077/rsyslogd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          18464      1070/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          17663      1032/master
***tcp6       0      0 :::60                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          14041      401/auditd***
tcp6       0      0 :::514                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          18571      1077/rsyslogd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          17023      759/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          18466      1070/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          17664      1032/master
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           0          14741      478/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           0          16016      549/dhclient
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                0          14742      478/chronyd

another confusion is all services are running on tcp and tcp6 but auditd is running on tcp6 only. is this something to be concerned about? 
On VM environment both tcp and tc6 lines are there for auditd.

Answer (score 0):

very small fix for this big question. 
Probably there are some issue with the network. I disabled auditd (systemctl disable auditd). After the instance starts, manually started auditd service (systemctl start auditd). This was a quick fix. I don't know the root cause though.